# How to store the old values using lightning select in onchange method

Tags: aura

I want to compare the selected old value with the selected new value in lightning aura options.
i was getting the same list which ever i changed newly.Could anyone help me how to get the old value using aura?
I tried following ways.

### Component:

```
<aura:attribute name="lstoftestcharge" type="List"/>
<td data-label="{!v.basketColumns[4]}" data-value="{!index}" onchange="{!c.onTypeChange}">   
<lightning:select aura:id="field" name="testcharge" class="table-input table-picklist" required="true"
                                                          value="{!accProduct.testcharge}" disabled="{!v.chargeTypeDisable}">
<aura:iteration items="{!v.lstoftestcharge}" var="testcharge">                            
                                                <option value="{!testcharge.value}" selected="{!testcharge.value == accProduct.testcharge}">{!testcharge.name}</option>
</aura:iteration>
</lightning:select>
</td>
```

### Controller:

```
onTypeChange : function(component, event, helper) {
        
       var olditems = component.get('v.selecteOld');
       alert('---olditems--->'+JSON.stringify(olditems));
      
       var items = component.get('v.selectedNew');           
       alert('---items--->'+JSON.stringify(items));
       
    },
```

In olditems and new items i am getting the same values which i changed newly.

Comment: Could someone help out here with any answer

Comment: @TSmith could someone help out with answer here